# Problem with calling function on server side in Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, server-side-rendering

I have next problem with my Next app
I have next method in my ArticleService class that call my sql db and has to return me all articles from my db

```
  async getArticles(): Promise<IArticle[] | ServiceError> {
    try {
      const reqArticles = await sql<IArticle>`
          SELECT * FROM articles
        `;
      const articles = reqArticles.rows;
      return articles;
    } catch (error) {
      return { message: "Cannot get articles" };
    }
  }
```

And here is a function that I call on frontend part

```
const getArticles = async () => await articles.getArticles();
```

Everything work absolutely great until I turn my page into "use client" and use next way to fetch data

```
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState<IArticle[]>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchArticles = async () => {
      const articlesData = await getArticles();

      setArticles(articlesData as IArticle[]);
    };
    fetchArticles();
  }, []);
```

I'm sure that db is not empty and I'm sure that same function but with getting articles by id works great. Can somebody explain my how can I prevent this kind of error?

Comment: Where do you import `sql` from? I'm sure it uses `"server-only"`. you should not query the database from the client. If you want to add a client-only to the `page.tsx`. just fetch the data on `page.tsx` and pass it as props to a client component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok gyus I've found out that accidentally next cached under the hood value of empty array, so I have to use `import {unstable_noStore } from "next/cache"` to solve this problem.